# ODBC DSN Authentication Options

Tags: authentication, odbc, dsn

I was wondering if besides the standard username/password ODBC authentication, other options exist to authenticate an ODBC connection using an alternate method like PKI similar to SSH.

Seems like a username / password not as secure if all I want is a server to server connection with no "real" user.  It would seem more secure to have the DB server only accept connections from the app server.

Comment: What database server are you using?  Several DBMS support authentication via certificate.

Comment: MS SQL, Oracle, etc. I am not the DBA, just a curious user.

Is there info out there on DBs that support certificate auth?

Comment: I suspect you will need to consult the vendor documentation for your favorite DBMS.

Comment: seems like the key to this is X509.  if the DB supports taht then you can do the cert based auth.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are other authentication methods.

Most DBMS-supplied "native" data access drivers (ODBC, JDBC, ADO.NET, OLE DB, XMLA, and others) are limited to UID/PWD.

MySQL (and possibly others) checks the client hostname and/or IP address as well as username and password.

Some third-party data access drivers [like the ones from my employer](http://uda.openlinksw.com/) add other authentication methods -- such as WebID, which leverages X509 technologies -- and attributes of the connection -- including but not limited to client IP address, application, operating system, and others.